# Django serializing view for model and non model serilizer

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

Expectation:

```
Expected output:
 { 

     "id": 123,
     "name": "abc",
     "body_measurement": 
           {
             "weight": 75,
             "bp": "normal,
             "bloodgroup": "A-positive",
           },
   }
```

models.py

```
class Health(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
     body_measurment = JSONField(_('measurments'),dump_kwargs={'indent': 4})
```

serializer.py

```
   class HealthSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Health
            fields = '__all__'

   class MeasurementSerializer(serializer,Serializer):

        weight = serializer.IntegerField()
        bp = serializer.CharField()
        bloodgroup = serializer.CharField()
```

views.py

```
   class HealthViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Health.objects.all()
        serializer_class = HealthSerializer
```

How can i add set of key values into the body_measurment with out adding in models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `JsonField` for `body_measurment` field on your model:

```
class HealthSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    body_measurement = serializers.JsonField()

        class Meta:
            model = Health
            fields = '__all__'
```

using this you can save any valid json in your body_measurement field

read about json field here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: how can i concat
 {
             "weight": 75,
             "bp": "normal,
             "bloodgroup": "A-positive",
   },
In views and to save in Healthmodel

Comment: use json.dumps() to get json representation of the dict

Comment: class HealthViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Health.objects.all()
        serializer_class = HealthSerializer

how to add in Viewset

Comment: how to add what? please edit your question to give more details.

Comment: Put (http://localhost:8000/health/123  )       
{
    "weight": 75,
    "bp": "normal,
    "bloodgroup": "A-positive",
  },
it should update as:
{ 

     "id": 123,
     "name": "abc",
     "body_measurement": 
           {
             "weight": 75,
             "bp": "normal,
             "bloodgroup": "A-positive",
           },
   }

Comment: @RameshK try the patch request it will let you update the object partially